# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I was curious about this integral so I asked about its convergence here: [Does $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)dx$ converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4856330/does-int-infty-infty-sin-1-left-frac-sinxx-rightdx-converge)

@jizert answered, explaining that it did converge. My follow-up question is what it converges to?

I pasted my work from the the other question below:

---

My attempts:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)$$
$$\sin\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$
$$x\sin\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)=\sin(x)$$
Seems like a dead end.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)dx$$
$$2\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)dx$$
$$2\int_{1}^{0}\sin^{-1}(u)\frac{du}{\frac{x\cos(x)-\sin(x)}{x^2}}$$
Also seems like a dead end because I can't figure out how to solve for $x$ in $u=\frac{\sin x}{x}$.

---

**Edit:** I also see that $\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|\le\left|\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)\right|\le\left|\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|$
but I doubt anything can be done with that.

Comment: I see no reason to think there is a closed-form expression for this value.

Comment: Not related to solving but you can say $x=\operatorname{sinc}^{-1}(u)$

Comment: Maybe someone else can apply the residue theory and get an infinite series. Also just maybe you can define $I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sin(i a\frac{\sin(x)}x),I’(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{i\sin(x)}{|x+ia\sin(x)|}dx$ and [solve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation) $u=x+i a\sin(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Taylor](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/197887/694899) expansion of $\arcsin{x}$, we have $$\arcsin (x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2 n}}\dbinom{2n}{n} \frac{x^{2 n+1}}{2 n+1}$$
and using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/378604/694899) result for integration of powers of $\sin(x)/x$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin^m(x)}{x^m} dx=\frac{\pi m}{2^m} \sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{m}{2}\right\rfloor} \frac{(-1)^k(m-2 k)^{m-1}}{k !(m-k) !}$$
Combining these two results, we obtain $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \arcsin{\left( \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)}dx = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dbinom{2n}{n} \frac{\pi}{2^{4n}} \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k (2(n-k)+1)^{2n}}{k! (2n-k+1)!} \approx 3.96.$$
Edit : Summing up $5000$ terms in the sum, the better approximation is $3.96363$.